# Filtering text while reading data into R with fread

Tags: r, filter, fread, text-manipulation

I have a large dataset and I wanted to read it in with fread, taking advantage of the select argument to only pick columns I need for this specific analysis. I was wondering if anyone knows a way that I could also filter a text column? something like dt %>% filter(str_detect(name, "Mary")) but in the fread function? Thanks.

Comment: That is not possible with `fread` but it is possible with package `sqldf`. This package accepts SQL statements making it very flexible but also slow to very slow. In the case of large files (how large is it?) it can save a lot of memory since it filters out what is not needed keeping only what is in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks. My dataset is about 1.4 GB and with fread it takes about 4 mins to be uploaded. Since there are a couple of these datasets that I work with, I think speed is really important for me.